# Error code 1452, difficulties with loading data into a table with a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to create a table with a foreign key but continue to get an error code 1452 where it states that it can't add or update a child row. I'm trying to link an account table with an `Account_ID` primary key to a payment table with an `Account_ID` foreign key. All the data matches values found in the parent table as well as the data type when creating both tables but I'm kind of lost as to what remedies could solve this.

I've dropped the payment table and created it again to make sure that I had the correct data types and referenced the correct table, in this case referencing the `acount` table (I know it's not spelled correctly but for some reason it wouldn't let me create an `account` table).

```
`CREATE TABLE PAYMENT
    (Payment_ID int(6) not null,
    payment_date date not null,
    payment_amount decimal(10,2) not null,
    Account_ID int(6) not null,

constraint pk_payment primary key (Payment_ID),

constraint fk_payment foreign key (Account_ID) references acount (Account_ID));`

CREATE TABLE ACOUNT 
    (Account_ID int(6) not null,
    Account_Balance decimal(10,2) not null,

constraint pk_acount primary key (Account_ID));`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change the order

```
CREATE TABLE ACOUNT 
    (Account_ID int(6) not null,
    Account_Balance decimal(10,2) not null,

constraint pk_acount primary key (Account_ID));`

  CREATE TABLE PAYMENT
  (Payment_ID int(6) not null,
  payment_date date not null,
  payment_amount decimal(10,2) not null,
  Account_ID int(6) not null,

  constraint pk_payment primary key (Payment_ID),

  constraint fk_payment foreign key (Account_ID) references acount (Account_ID));
```

creating PAYMENT first you try to access  to a table and a column that not exist ..